# useradd command in linux not working as expected?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, useradd

I tried to change default shell in Ubuntu 14.04 using the following command

```
user@MyUbuntu:~$ sudo useradd -D -s /bin/tcsh
user@MyUbuntu:~$ sudo useradd -D 
GROUP=101
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/sh
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no
```

Why defaults are not getting updated. I reboot the pc, but values still not updating. Why ?

**Update**: **I don't want to add a new user, i want to update some defaults using useradd command**

Comment: @Rinzwind but it is not working i tried many times.

Comment: yes tcsh is installed

Comment: useradd is creating new user , but it's not updating any default values. I am reading. Linux command line and shell scripting - bible.2nd editor, in which the author demonstrated useradd to change default shell.

Comment: I consider this a BUG. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/useradd.8.html and the part that starts with "Changing the default values" it states "-D" followed by options changes the default. And "-s" is the one for the shell.

Comment: @Rinzwind so i should report a bug ?

Comment: Check the permissions of `/etc/default/useradd`.

Comment: @nephente - rw- --- --- this is the permission

Comment: Try making the change to /etc/default/useradd directly and see if useradd -D picks up on the change then.

Comment: @takkat for adding users YES. But this is for editing the defaults and that should still work. and the dupe is NOT a dupe.

Comment: @cody I tend to be on the side believing it is a bug. I have seen it work on 14.04 as expected (proven also by the answer) and I have a 15.04 where this does NOT work (granted: the 2 systems are both not vanilla so there is doubt)

Comment: So I moved my `/etc/default/useradd` file to `useradd.bak` and then running `sudo useradd -D -s /bin/mksh`   created new file which does have `SHELL=/bin/mksh` . You may want to try doing that. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `adduser` command. The adduser command is a Perl implementation of useradd (which is a C binary).

```
$ cat /usr/sbin/adduser | grep useradd
    my $useradd = &which('useradd');
        &systemcall($useradd, '--extrausers', '-d', $home_dir, '-g', $ingroup_name, '-s',
        &systemcall($useradd, '-d', $home_dir, '-g', $ingroup_name, '-s',
    my $useradd = &which('useradd');
        &systemcall($useradd, '--extrausers', '-d', $home_dir, '-g', $ingroup_name, '-s',
        &systemcall($useradd, '-d', $home_dir, '-g', $ingroup_name, '-s',
    # useradd without -p has left the account disabled (password string is '!')
```

adduser takes care of everything, i.e whether the user has been added to the `/etc/passwd` file or not.

Answer (score 0):

For me changes are applying and I think I did same as you did.

```
gennu@gennu:~$ sudo useradd -D -s /bin/tcsh 

gennu@gennu:~$ useradd -D
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no


gennu@gennu:~$ sudo useradd -D
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no
gennu@gennu:~$
```

But I didnt see changes were done in my /etc/passwd file.

```
gennu@gennu:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep 'root\|gennu'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
gennu:x:1000:1000:gennu,,,:/home/gennu:/bin/bash
```

Comment: `useradd -D` just changes the default values for new accounts as stored in `/etc/default/useradd`. If you need to change the login shell for an existing user, use `usermod -s` or edit `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Raja are you using ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: So the plot thickens...  this should be the expected result

Comment: 15.04 it does NOT work. `sudo useradd -D -s /bin/tcsh` and I still get `SHELL=/bin/sh`

Comment: I m using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS